# Rename Nested Columns with dot with Actual Column Name Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have spark rowdataset.
I want to rename each and every level columnname which contains dot with actual column name
Below is my RowDataSet

```
{
"UnifiedIndividual__dlm": {"ssot__Id__c":"0018830e6c54003706118e54127b26b0",
                           "IndividualIdentityLink__dlm":[{
                                     "Individua.SourceRecordId__c":"1000009375",
                                     "Individua.UnifiedRecordId__c":"0018830e6c54003706118e54127b26b0",
                                     "ssot__Individual":[{
                                           "Individual1.FirstName__c":"testfirst",
                                           "Individual1.Id__c":"1000009375",
                                           "Individual1.LastName__c":"testlast"
                                     }]
                           }]
                       }
}
```

Here SourceRecordId__c and UnifiedRecordId__c are coming as
Individua.SourceRecordId__c and Individua.UnifiedRecordId__c
Similarly FirstName__c and LastName__c are coming with parent names.

Expected Output

```
  "UnifiedIndividual__dlm": {"ssot__Id__c":"0018830e6c54003706118e54127b26b0",
                              "IndividualIdentityLink__dlm":[{
                                        "SourceRecordId__c":"1000009375",
                                        "UnifiedRecordId__c":"0018830e6c54003706118e54127b26b0",
                                        "ssot__Individual":[{
                                              "FirstName__c":"testfirst",
                                              "Id__c":"1000009375",
                                              "LastName__c":"testlast"
                                        }]
                              }]
                          }
}


There can be multiple nested levels and field name are not unique. 
Is there any way in Spark we can just extract the last name as column name which contains dot.
```